# What should be the policy regarding character-specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is going to be a very short question. Sooner or later people will start creating tags of popular characters, e.g., [kurosaki-ichigo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kurosaki-ichigo).

What should be our policy regarding them? AFAIK they are not usually allowed on SCIFI.SE, but they also have exceptions such as [c3po](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c3po), or [spock](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spock).

Should we generally allow or forbid using such tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that usually they don't have really a reason to exist, unless

- It's a very prominent character, that stands out;
- There are many questions about this specific character.

For example, on SciFi, there is a [voldemort](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voldemort) tag. It **is** a prominent character (the main antagonist and what an antagonist!) and there are **80 questions** with this tag. That makes it a good tag. There will definitely be people searching for this tag.

One single tag about [character-from-anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-from-anime) would probably be too little. Is it really an interesting character, widely appreciated? If the question is no, it probably doesn't deserve a tag.

In any case, we don't need to take all the decisions now. I think it's best if we decide as we go on, keeping the tags we realize work and cutting those that we see have no reason to exist. But what I said will give us some parameters to decide and to anticipate what tags might work and which ones wouldn't.

Comment: I'd love to have my own tag, [tag:madara-uchiha] has a nice ring to it :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue we should collectively disallow them. Even if the intention is good, things will get out of hand real quick.

Imagine the following:

> #### "What is the relationship between Naruto, Sasuke and Sakura?"
>
> [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto)[naruto-uzumaki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-uzumaki)[sasuke-uchiha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sasuke-uchiha)[sakura-haruno](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sakura-haruno)

Even if you do limit to "only notable characters" or "only protagonists/antagonists", the line is far to blurred out to be used correctly.

Comment: I concur! A simple [tag:character] tag or equivalent would suffice.

Comment: I agree but only as a general rule. Some characters do deserve a special tag. :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Like which? I can't think of a character so notable, so distinctly important that it deserves a tag at the same level of entire anime titles.

Comment: I **have** to agree with Madara (he used genjutsu). No really, I agree with Madara.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Again, it's not something we must define a priori.  Besides, the fact you can't think of one does not prove there isn't one. :P We're still in private beta, remember! :P

Comment: Characters from different anime that have the same name are another landmine. In fact, at least in my case, this problem can occur *within* one anime. I am one of the most popular characters in the Fate franchise, but I am known primarily to most of my fans as "Saber" rather than "King Arthur" or "Arturia Pendragon". However, in the Fate universe, the "Saber" Servant Class encompasses quite a number of other characters.